# How to set every nth element equal to K

Tags: r

Given a vector of say n normal realisations, how can I change every 9th element to be 0?

```
X<-rnorm(1000)
X<-X[ c(9,18,27,...) ] <- 0
```

I'm not sure how I can make a function for the above (i'd be interested to see a method without loops if this will increase the speed)

Comment: Read about `?seq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `seq`

```
X[ seq(9, length(X), by = 9)] <- 0
```

Comment: Won't make a big difference I assume, but because OP mentioned speed - maybe also mention `seq.int` ?